# how to formatting substring to link twitter-like using javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, format

for example I have string like this :

```
Hi @david I want to eat chicken. #kfc #yummy
```

I want to format it be like this :

```
<p> Hi <a href="/u/david">@david</a> I want to eat chicken. <a href="/tag/kfc">#kfc</a> <a href="/tag/yummy">#yummy</a></p>
```

how to convert string to that html-format like twitter?

using java script?

Answer (score 0):

```js
('Hi @david I want to eat chicken. #kfc #yummy')
.replace(/@([a-z]+)/g, '<a href="/u/$1">@$1</a>')
.replace(/#([a-z]+)/g, '<a href="/tag/$1">#$1</a>');
```

Working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/rgwLhesc/

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to an array of words, and then check if the word contains either `@` or `#`, if so, create an anchor element, otherwise a text node and append to `p`. For example:

```js
let p = document.createElement("p");
let tweet = "Hi @david I want to eat chicken. #kfc #yummy";
for (let word of tweet.split(" ")) {
  if (word.startsWith("@")) {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.textContent = word;
    a.href = `/u/${word.substr(1)}`;
    p.append(a);
  } else if (word.startsWith("#")) {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.textContent = word;
    a.href = `/tag/${word.substr(1)}`;
    p.append(a);
  } else {
    p.append(document.createTextNode(word));
  }
  p.append(" ");
}
container.append(p);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```